# I can't log into my ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, login

When I try to log in on my **Ubuntu 12.04** it goes to a black screen ( of logging in checking stuff ), and says `Checking battery   -----     [ok]` ( I'm using a computer instead of a laptop ) and just goes back to the login screen.

---

Two days before I executed the command `sudo startx` trying to start KDE, but it didn't work. And after logging off and trying to log in again, I had this problem.

A big problem is that I don't have internet connection at home.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it without the battery plugged in. Remove the battery, plug in the power source (this works with most laptops, but I've seen a few that **required** the battery to be installed) and see if you get the same issue. If you do it's likely one of two things:

1. Your battery has a special driver that somehow got corrupted in linux
2. Your battery is failing

Does this occur after you enter your password in, or do you never get to the login screen where you would enter your password?

I see you're using KDE - are you using KDE on an Ubuntu system, or are you using straight up Kubuntu?